# Magento2.3.1 issue with payment via authorized.net

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, authorize.net

I have configured the authorized.net using production details (which are completely working fine on one if my magento2 store).
I am using the same card for payment test that I have used on my another Magento2 store.

Now when I entered the card details and click on place order it shows me the error message :

> {"message":"**Invalid gateway credentials**.", "trace":"#0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(453,
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...',
>   Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(453,
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#3
>   /var/www/html//generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...',
>   Array, Array)\n#4 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(453,
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#5
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#6
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))\n#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#8
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#9
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#10
>   /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#11
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(136):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#12
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#13
>   /var/www/html/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#14
>   {main}"}

Console: **https://mytestweb.com/magento/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information** (Where I got this response).

Comment: you got any solution?